# Formation of Magnetic Field from Moving Charge

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there a derivation of the magnetic field from the electric field of a charge q moving with speed v? (I know that there are some online, but my limited knowledge in multivariable calculus does not help in understanding such derivations.)

I understand conceptually how a changing electric field can produce a magnetic field but I do not understand it mathematically.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking. The (relativistic) electromagnetic field generated by a moving charge is given by the [Liénard-Wiechert potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential), and "mathematically" a changing electric field produces a magnetic field through [Ampère's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law), which in differential form, in suitable units, reads
$$ \nabla \times \textbf B = \textbf J + \dot{\textbf E}.$$ Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to explain it without using curl?

Comment: You can express it in integral form if you want, as written in the [wikipedia article](http://tinyurl.com/lco3nap) linked above. Again, you should be more specific in what you don't understand.